# Open vscode info window in tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am currently using visual studio code `version 1.14.2` and they have some nice little info windows for certain named properties. I am not 100% sure if this is just the case for angular development, but below is an example writing with the ionic framework and angular.

[image]

So when you hover over `@IonicPage()` there is this large amount of text explaining a heck of lot. Its just a bit tedious scrolling through it in the pop up window and was wondering if there is a shortcut to open that in another tab side by side?

Update:

I see that if one howvers over `@IonicPage()` and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> opens the reference in a new window. However this is the `d.ts` and so is formatted as one long comment. Which is not ideal, as in the pop up it is properly formatted markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of VSCode 1.15, you cannot relocate the intellisense widget. I believe this is tracked by: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21769